# Order of evaluation when using Nearest within NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation

I'm having some trouble with evaluation order within `NIntegrate`. Here's a simple example:

```
pts = {{-0.2, -0.2}, {0.2, 0.2}};
NIntegrate[Nearest[pts-> "Distance", {x, y}] , {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]
(*Nearest: The default distance does not give a real numeric distance when 
applied to the point pair {x,y} and {-0.2,-0.2}.*)
```

Is there some way I can get the numerical integration to plug the values of `x` and `y` into `Nearest` rather than passing the variables themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nearly a "duplicate" of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) (link is to the `?NumericQ` answer) -- please see it for explanation.  In this case, there are a few other things to add to make the integration work efficiently:

```
pts = {{-0.2, -0.2}, {0.2, 0.2}};
Block[{f, nf},
 nf = Nearest[pts -> "Distance"]; (* precompute NearestFunction *)
 f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] :=   (* NumericQ prevents evaluation on symbolic x, y *)
   First@nf[{x, y}];              (* Nearest returns a list; extract distance with First *)
 NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[]]
 ]
(*  1.69082  *)
```

Comment: I read some of that thread quite a while back. At the time I didn't understand much of it. Now I see what a great resource it is. I guess I've only just attained the sophistication of a `new user`. Before I was just a `n00b`. Anyway, many thanks!